# Is it possible that a 32-bit operating system use more than 4 GB memory, and how?

Tags: x86, operating-system, 32-bit

Most of the 32-bit operating system generally use 4 GB of physical memory, and I should use a MATLAB toolbox which only install on the 32-bit OS. Could you please suggest me a 32-bit OS which use more than 4 GB memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 32-bit operating system typically uses 32-bit virtual addresses; which limits a single virtual address space to 4 GiB (which is often split into "user-space" and "kernel space", so that a process in "user space" might only get 2 GiB or 3 GiB of space).

Virtual addresses are converted into physical addresses. This conversion normally uses (a hierarchy of) tables, where the final physical addresses can be a completely different size to the virtual address size. For a specific example; the PAE (physical address extension) feature on 80x86 (introduced in the 1990s) allowed the physical address size to be 36 bits, but it was extended (when another feature, "long mode" was introduced in the 2000s) and now PAE supports even larger physical addresses (up to a "current architectural maximum" of 52 bits).

Essentially; it's like an array where the size of the index is different to the size of an entry (e.g. like "`uint64_t myArray[ my8bitIndex]`", or like "`uint52_t myPageTable[my32bitVirtualAddress]`"); except it's not actually a single array (and has multiple levels so that you don't need to waste space for large areas of "unused").

Of course different CPUs have different limits (some 80x86 CPUs only support 36 bit physical addresses, some support 48 bit physical addresses, ...); and the amount of RAM installed is always smaller than the amount of physical address space a CPU supports (because parts of the physical address space are used for ROM, devices, etc; and because RAM costs money and large amounts of RAM costs large amounts of money).

For an actual example; if a computer has 32 GiB of RAM; then a 32 bit OS could run 100 processes with 3 GiB of space each (300 GiB of total "user space"), but most of that space will be unused and pieces of it will be the same RAM mapped into many different virtual address spaces, so those 100 processes might only use 12 GiB of RAM; and then the OS might use the remaining 20 GiB of RAM to cache file system data (where data for files can be cached in RAM without that RAM being mapped into any virtual address space until/unless a process wants it).